# How is $\mathrm{d}s$ related to $\mathrm{d}r$ in vector calculus? Also, what is $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}$ in vector calculus?

Tags: calculus

How is $\mathrm{d}s$ related to $\mathrm{d}r$ in vector calculus? Also, what is $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}$ in vector calculus?

I know that $\mathrm{d}s$ signifies the length of a curve, and $\mathrm{d}r$ is like a tangent.

Comment: Are you learning vector calculus from a textbook? The textbook should explain all of the notation it uses. The notations $ds$ and $dr$ don't mean anything out of context, and as far as I know, $dr/dt$ just means the derivative of $r$ with respect to $t$--and $r$ and $t$ don't mean anything out of context. If you're having trouble understanding some notation, can you quote the entire passage?

Answer (score 1):

$dr$ is a vector quantity, equal to $<dx, dy>$.  Informally, it signifies an infinitesimal change in the position of an object:  if an object is at position $<x, y>$ and moves a tiny bit, its new position is $<x + dx, y + dy>$, and the change in position is $<dx, dy>$.

$\frac{dr}{dt}$ is also a vector quantity,  equal to $\left<\frac{dx}{dt},  \frac{dy}{dt}\right>$.  It denotes the instantaneous velocity of an object.

$ds$, on the other hand, is a *scalar* quantity.  Informally, it represents a tiny bit of length along the path of an object.  If an object moves a distance $dx$ in the $x$ direction and $dy$ in the $y$ direction, then by the Pythagorean theorem it has moved a total distance of $ds = \sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2}$.  You can see that $ds = \left| dr \right|$.

$ds$ is  also often expressed in terms of $dt$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
ds &= \sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2} \\ 
&= \sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2   \right)(dt)^2} \\
&=  \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2   }\hskip{8pt} dt
\end{align}$$